# Rails saving virtual attributes in a DB column as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The way my app is constructed I thought that this is the best way to handle these non model attributes. I have a bunch of inputs that I want to save as an array in my db, but i'm not exactly sure how to do this. I know I have to pass the params to the create action in the controller.

_form.html.erb

```
<% @product_sizes_array.each do |ps| %>
  <%= text_field_tag ps %>
<% end %>
```

How should my create action look?

Orders_controller.rb

```
def new
  @product_sizes_array = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL']
end
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if @order.save
    redirect_to edit_order_path(@order), notice: 'Order was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post what you have so far.

Comment: @NickM Ok I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish here, so I'm having to make a few assumptions.  For right now I'm assuming that a customer places an order, and that the text box for each size is how many of that size you are wanting to order.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  #id
end

#An ordered item, order specific
class Order::Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, class_name: '::Item'
  #id
  #order_id => points to the order this item belongs to
  #item_id => points to Item
  #size_id => points to an index in the array of sizes
  #value => number of items ordered

  def size
    self.class.int_to_size(self.size_id)
  end

  def self.int_to_size size_id
    ::Item::PRODUCT_SIZES[size_id]
  end

  def self.string_to_size_index name
    ::Item::PRODUCT_SIZES.index{|s| s == name }
  end
end

#Individual item, not size specific
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  PRODUCT_SIZES = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL']
  #id
  #name
  #price
end
```

So the way this works is that the user submits an array of sizes corresponding to how many of each size they want.  You create an Order, then insert into Order::Item the current order_id, the selected item_id, it's corresponding size, and how many of that size they want.